# Can I make a type like "strings that are possibly undefined"

Tags: typescript

*Note: I have `--strictNullChecks` turned on*

I have a function like this:

```
export function ensure<T, F extends T>(maybe: T | undefined, fallback: F): T {
  if (isDefined<T>(maybe)) {
    return maybe
  }

  if (fallback === undefined) {
    throw new Error('Could not ensure a value; please supply a fallback for the given variable')
  }

  return fallback
}
```

I use it to get rid of the `undefined` part of a possibly undefined value.

```
const user = ensure(possiblyUndefinedUser, defaultUser)
```

I would like the following,

```
const user = ensure(certainlyDefinedUser, defaultUser)
```

to be a compile time error. ie I want it to be illegal to use this function with a value that the compiler believes has a value. (this will force me to type my functions correctly, see below)

I've tried a number of variations on the generic arguments, to get a type like `T | undefined` where values of type `T` are not assignable to it. I realize that this might not be possible but I thought I would consult the community rather than keep toiling.

---

My goal here is: if I want to pass an argument through a function like `isNil` or `ensure`, then I want to be forced to change the argument type to be optional. If an argument is not optional, then I should be 100% confident that there is no need to null check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use conditional type to trigger an error on the second parameter if the first can't be undefined.

```
function isDefined<T>(v: T) : v is Exclude<T, undefined> {
    return !!v;
}

export function ensure<T, F extends (undefined extends T ? T : 'First param can\'t be undefined')>(maybe: T, fallback: F): Exclude<T, undefined> {
    if (isDefined<T>(maybe)) {
        return maybe
    }

    if (fallback === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Could not ensure a value; please supply a fallback for the given variable')
    }
    //We need a type assertion here as F tehnically might not extend T
    return fallback as any;
}

declare var defaultUser: string|undefined;
declare var possiblyUndefinedUser: string| undefined
const user = ensure(possiblyUndefinedUser, defaultUser) //ok

declare var certainlyDefinedUser: string;
const user2 = ensure(certainlyDefinedUser, defaultUser); //error
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20isDefined<T>(v%3A%20T)%3A%20v%20is%20Exclude<T%2C%20undefined>%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20!!v%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20ensure<T%2C%20F%20extends%20(undefined%20extends%20T%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20'First%20param%20can%5C't%20be%20undefined')>(maybe%3A%20T%2C%20fallback%3A%20F)%3A%20Exclude<T%2C%20undefined>%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isDefined<T>(maybe))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20maybe%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(fallback%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error('Could%20not%20ensure%20a%20value%3B%20please%20supply%20a%20fallback%20for%20the%20given%20variable')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2FWe%20need%20a%20type%20assertion%20here%20as%20F%20tehnically%20might%20not%20extend%20T%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20fallback%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20defaultUser%3A%20string%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20possiblyUndefinedUser%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0Aconst%20user%20%3D%20ensure(possiblyUndefinedUser%2C%20defaultUser)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20certainlyDefinedUser%3A%20string%3B%0D%0Aconst%20user2%20%3D%20ensure(certainlyDefinedUser%2C%20defaultUser)%3B) you need to manually select strict null checks.

Comment: Hmm, `undefined extends T` is interesting. When I played around with this in the playground and replaced `defaultUser` with `'bob' as string | undefined` I received the following error: `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '"First param can't be undefined"'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '"First param can't be undefined"'.`

Comment: I think `undefined extends T` is on the right track, since it means "undefined is assignable to T"

Comment: @Ziggy wops, made the fallback allow undefined

Comment: This works! It's a little weird that we have to make the second param report on the first... it's the buddy system.

Comment: @Ziggy yeah... It's a bit difficult, we have to create a incompatibility somewhere since I don't know of a way to exclude types without `undefined ` using extends (don't think there is one)

Comment: This kind of a function is very useful: it lets you find places in your code where you have not marked a value optional, but you are treating it as though it is optional. Since accepting your answer, I have found 30 such bugs ;) in each case I can decide whether 1. the value should have been optional, or 2. the value should not be checked. It makes code very clean!

Comment: @Ziggy glad it's useful :)

Comment: Currently though, there may not be a way to do this with a function like `isNil` which takes just one argument, right? We need to use the second argument to tattle on the first. Would this make a good issue in the typescript github?

Comment: @Ziggy  I'm think about this and I'll keep thinking... but I haven't found a way to create an incompatibility in a function with a single argument. I suggest asking a follow up question, maybe someone else has an idea...

Comment: @Ziggy This seems to work, but I am currently on my phone onin the ts playground so I can see the error :`function isDefined<T>(v: T & (undefined extends T ? 'error' : {})): boolean {
  return !v;
}`

Comment: When I try this it works: `function isDefined<T>(v: T & (undefined extends T ? any : never)): boolean {
  return !v
}` however, v has `any` in the types (but that's not a huuuuuge problem here since, really, T is basically any).